# How do I show the color preview next to color name?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, colors, preview

I am currently developing a mobile application with Flutter. I want to show the color preview and the colors in dropdown list like this:

[image: ColorPreview]

How can I do it? Is there any package I can import?

*They are all Turkish words. (Kırmızı=red, mavi=blue, sarı=yellow etc.)

Comment: I give You a hint, You can do it with these Widgets: `ListView`, `ListTile` with name of colors as `title` and an `Icon` with color as it's `tailing`.You can also show your code to get more help on it.

Comment: What have you tried?  Stack overflow would like you to have a minimal reproducible example before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PaintColors{
  String colorName;
  var preview;

PaintColors(this.colorName, this.preview);

paintTheIcon(String name) {
switch (name) {
  case 'Kırmızı':
    preview = Icon(
      Icons.brightness_1,
      color: Colors.red,
    );
    break;

case 'Beyaz':
    preview = Icon(
      Icons.brightness_1,
      color: Colors.white,
    );
    break;
}
return preview;
}
}
```

I've created this class and tried to put them into list like:

```
static List<PaintColors> colorList = [('Beyaz', paintTheIcon('Beyaz'))];
```

...
but it didn't work.